# How to change levelplot font family?

Tags: r, fonts, levelplot

I need to change the text font family of levelplot graph, I trying this but no success:

```
levelplot(a,main=list(label="title",cex=1,fontfamily = "sans" ))
```

or

```
levelplot(a,main=list(label="title",cex=1,font = 3 ))
```

Nothing change. I want to change for Times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a lot of those settings in the `trellis.par.get()` list. To override them for a specific plot with a `par.settings` parameter. Here an example using the test code from the `levelplot` page

```
x <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
r <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- cos(r^2) * exp(-r/(pi^3))
levelplot(z~x*y, grid, cuts = 50, scales=list(log="e"), xlab="",
    ylab="", main="Weird Function", sub="with log scales",
    colorkey = FALSE, region = TRUE,
    par.settings=list(axis.text=list(fontfamily="serif"),
    par.xlab.text=list(fontfamily="serif"),
    par.ylab.text=list(fontfamily="serif"),
    par.main.text=list(fontfamily="serif"),
    par.sub.text=list(fontfamily="serif")
))
```

[image: plot with serif font]

Comment: Thanks, I still new with handle graphs in R, thanks. I will read about par.settings. Thanks again.